# Casting Linq to IEnumerable <Datarow>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating winForm app,In that Onbutton click i gather  Data Tables from of Two database  Mysql and Sqlite database. 
I getting Casting error while on casting Linq query to IEnumerable to make fetch query values to DataTable to make display in DataGrid view.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var obj = new table1TableAdapter();  //Mysql Table Adapter
    var obj2 = new Table1TableAdapter(); // Sqlite Table Adapter
    var ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(obj.GetData());
    ds.Tables.Add(obj2.GetData());
    var tab1 = ds.Tables[0];
    var tab2 = ds.Tables[1];
    var query = from o in tab1.AsEnumerable()
                join od in tab2.AsEnumerable()
                on o.Field<string>("Name") equals od.Field<string>("Name")
                select new
                {
                    Name = o.Field<string>("Name"),
                    Rollno = od.Field<Int64>("rollno"),
                    Book = o.Field<string>("Book")
                };

    var q2 = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)query; //Unable to cast object of type <JoinIterator>

    DataTable orderTable = q2.CopyToDataTable();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = orderTable;
}
```

Comment: That isn't a DataRow, and you can't magically turn it into a `DataRow`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'd say, why cast it to `IEnumerable<DataRow>` at all ? Just simply bind the query to your GridView.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because the query object you are returning has no relation to `DataRow`. `query` is going to be an IEnumerable<**SomeAnonymousType**>. How is it expected to convert to `DataRow`?

You would need to alter your statement to make a DataRow:

```
select new DataRow(/* Whatever Params */) { /* More Params */ };
```

Then it's natively an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and needs no casting.

Answer (score 3):

Since your query is creating an IEnumerable you wouldn't be able to cast it to a DataRow. I also wouldn't not advise using select new DataRow(/* Whatever Params */) { /* More Params */ }; since this would not be a true DataRow object and would be bad practice.

I would handle it this way. Even if this is a small project, there shouldn't be that much code in your Button_Click handler.

First, create a container object, call it a DTO or ViewModel. I suggest the later.

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Int64 Rollno { get; set; }

    public string Book { get; set; }
}
```

Next, create a new class that will do your SQL queries. This will separate your Data Access logic from your form logic.

```
public class BookService
{
    public IList<BookViewModel> GetBookViewModel()
    {
        var obj = new table1TableAdapter();  //Mysql Table Adapter
        var obj2 = new Table1TableAdapter(); // Sqlite Table Adapter
        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(obj.GetData());
        ds.Tables.Add(obj2.GetData());
        var tab1 = ds.Tables[0];
        var tab2 = ds.Tables[1];
        var query = from o in tab1.AsEnumerable()
                    join od in tab2.AsEnumerable()
                    on o.Field<string>("Name") equals od.Field<string>("Name")
                    select new BookViewModel
                    {
                        Name = o.Field<string>("Name"),
                        Rollno = od.Field<Int64>("rollno"),
                        Book = o.Field<string>("Book")
                    };

        return query.ToList();
    }

}
```

Last, bind the List to your display.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BookService bookService = new BookService();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bookService.GetBookViewModel();
    }
```

Now when you go back to make changes to your code, you will easily be able to modify your display logic and with out having to read through all of your intermixed code.

Example:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BookService bookService = new BookService();
            IList<BookViewModel> books = bookService.GetBookViewModel();
            if (books.Count == 0)
            {
                        Label1.Text = "Sorry no books were found";
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = books;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you're not going to be able to cast to an IEnumerable because you're query itself is not producing DataRows

```
select new
{
    Name = o.Field<string>("Name"),
    Rollno = od.Field<Int64>("rollno"),
    Book = o.Field<string>("Book")
};
```

is creating an anonymous type.

You would have to change this to a DataRow somehow first, and then convert it to an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following statement and this works for me

```
UC070_WizardStepFilesDataSet.AllDossierDetailResultsRow[] searchrows =
                        (from a in _wizardStepPreviewDataSet.AllDossierDetailResults
                        where a.WingsSetNbr == row.WingsSetNbr && !a.BookCode.StartsWith("V")
                        select a).ToArray<UC070_WizardStepFilesDataSet.AllDossierDetailResultsRow>();
```